# You may know me - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

Though I am just a man,
You may be quite a fan.
You may think I cannot die,
You may have seen my taxi fly.

Later I saved everyone,
I'll make you cry, even the sun.
Then suddenly I was dead,
Don't let that get to your head.

I took some time, went back and forth,
Found great strength, and great worth.
Thought I could settle down,
That didn't work, just made me frown.

I have many well known friends,
They think we can be thrown away, in the end.
Figure now who I may be,
And where you often see me.

Comment: At first I thought "could it be bubble buddy?", and now I can't think about the real answer without that in my head.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> Bruce Willis
>
>  Though I am just a man,
>  You may be quite a fan.
>  You may think I cannot die, [`Die Hard`]
>  You may have seen my taxi fly. [`The Fifth Element`]
>
>  Later I saved everyone,
>  I'll make you cry, even the sun. [`Tears of the Sun`]
>  Then suddenly I was dead, [`The Sixth Sense`] 
>  Don't let that get to your head.
>
>  I took some time, went back and forth, [`Looper`]
>  Found great strength, and great worth.
>  Thought I could settle down, [`RED`]
>  That didn't work, just made me frown.
>
>  I have many well known friends,
>  They think we can be thrown away, in the end. [`The Expendables`]
>  Figure now who I may be,
>  And where you often see me.

Thank you for all the remarks that suggested improvements/corrections. Much obliged. Also. Nicely crafted puzzle.

Comment: Can you better explain how it fits each line / stanza?

Comment: Welcome to S.E. Puzzling. Can you please add some justification as to why you believe that fits the answer? I might also recommend looking at some other puzzles to see the format often used when answering riddles. Especially, I would like to point out the '>!' formatting option at the beginning of a line which will hide your answers.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling SE! You might want to give a more detailed explanation (It'll avoid you getting downvotes) It's certainly an interesting answer, I see Die Hard fitting for the first paragraph but you kind of lose me after that!

Comment: Another movie where he seems to have retired and is unhappy is G.I.Joe: Retaliation.   Good explanation, you seem to have found all the movies first : )

Comment: Fifth Element, not Fifth Sense ;)

Comment: Nicely done! I was also thinking Armageddon and The Kid in their, but everything you said works!

Comment: TBH the Armageddon reference was too generic and so it never occurred to me (as the others were more specific). Regarding The Kid, I  saw it so many years ago I (almost) forgot about it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you...

> Bruce Willis?

Though I am just a man,
You may be quite a fan.
You may think I cannot die,
You may have seen my taxi fly.

> Bruce Willis is a man, and as an actor he has lots of fans. He cannot die in *Unbreakable* and flew a taxi in *The Fifth Element*

Later I saved everyone,
I'll make you cry, even the sun.
Then suddenly I was dead,
Don't let that get to your head.

> He saved everyone in the *Die Hard* films and in *Tears of the Sun*, which is what the 2nd line is referencing (Thanks @Spacemonkey). He turned out to be *SPOILERS!!* dead in *The Sixth Sense*.

I took some time, went back and forth,
Found great strength, and great worth.
Thought I could settle down,
That didn't work, just made me frown.

> Bruce Willis went back and forth between different types of movies? Or maybe making/not making movies? And ended up not being happy if he wasn't filming? (I'm not 100% sure about this one)

I have many well known friends,
They think we can be thrown away, in the end.
Figure now who I may be,
And where you often see me.

> He appears with many other well known action heros in *The Expendables*, but alas, he is not expendable. You're Bruce Willis! And I often see you in these films.

Comment: Tears of the Sun (war movie) for the 2nd paragraph - and I have a feeling the saving anyone clue is probably more for Armageddon as in the scope of that movie he truly saves **everyone**  For the third going back and forth taking his time, it might be a reference to the timetravel movie Looper

Comment: Nicely done. Unfortunately just after the first. +1 for sure though.